# Python xml ElementTree findall returns empty result

Tags: python, xml, python-2.7

I would like to parse following XML file using the Python xml ElementTree API.

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
<foos>
  <foo_table>

    <!-- bar -->
    <fooelem>
      <fname>BBBB</fname>
      <group>SOMEGROUP</group>
      <module>some module</module>
    </fooelem>
  
    <fooelem>
      <fname>AAAA</fname>
      <group>other group</group>
      <module>other module</module>
    </fooelem>
    <!-- bar -->

  </foo_table>
</foos>
```

In this example code I try to find all the elements under `/foos/foo_table/fooelem/fname` but obviously `findall` doesn't find anything when running this code.

```py
import xml.etree.cElementTree as ET
tree = ET.ElementTree(file="min.xml")
for i in tree.findall("./foos/foo_table/fooelem/fname"): 
    print i

root = tree.getroot()
for i in root.findall("./foos/foo_table/fooelem/fname"): 
    print i
```

I am not experienced with the ElementTree API, but I've used the example under https://docs.python.org/2/library/xml.etree.elementtree.html#example. Why is it not working in my case?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`foos` is your `root`, you would need to start `findall` below, e.g.

```
root = tree.getroot()
for i in root.findall("foo_table/fooelem/fname"): 
    print i.text
```

Output:

```
BBBB
AAAA
```

Comment: Thanks. Is there a specific reason to chose root.findall() instead of tree.findall()? It seems that both show the same result.

Comment: @ThoWe: No reason I am aware of, my guess would be that it is just convention.

Answer (score 1):

This is because the path you are using begins BEFORE the root element (`foos`). 
Use this instead: `foo_table/fooelem/fname`

Comment: For beating me by 8 seconds.

Answer (score 0):

`findall` doesn't work, but this does:

```
e = xml.etree.ElementTree.parse(myfile3).getroot()
mylist=list(e.iter('checksum'))
print (len(mylist))
```

mylist will have the proper length.

Comment: Code-only answers are discouraged. Please edit your answer and add some explanation to your code.